# DQL - Merge custom value within entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

Sooo, I have a problem with an DQL Query...

```
->createQuery(
    "SELECT cjr, cjr.microtimeEnd - cjr.microtimeStart AS duration
        FROM Application\Entity\CronJobResultEntity cjr"
)
```

This works, but now I get an array as response, but I want the "duration" value within the entity (or in other words...be part of that entity), which means, it should be something like that:

```
->createQuery(
    "SELECT cjr, cjr.microtimeEnd - cjr.microtimeStart AS cjr.duration
        FROM Application\Entity\CronJobResultEntity cjr"
)
```

But that throws an exception:

```
QueryException in QueryException.php line 52:
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 56: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'
```

Anybody has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a duration field in the entity?

Comment: No, like in the example above you see, that's it's calculated "on the fly".

EDIT: Also tried to add the field to the entity. Didn't helped.

Comment: Do you have the option to change the database structure, or the raw entity code?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to booth.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you are doing is more of a SQL approach.  To make it more DQL like, add a 'duration' and getters and setters to your entity code:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $duration;

/**
 * Get duration
 *
 * @return
 */

public function getDuration() {
     return $this->duration;
}

/**
 * Set duration
 *
 * @param
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDuration($duration) {
    $this->duration = $duration;
    return $this;
}
```

Use your first query.

```
->createQuery(
    "SELECT cjr, cjr.microtimeEnd - cjr.microtimeStart AS duration
        FROM Application\Entity\CronJobResultEntity cjr"
);
```

Then get the results.

```
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Finally rip through them to set the data (you could also do foreach if it makes more sense to you).

```
array_map(
    function($r){
        $r->setDuration($r->getMicroTimeEnd() - $r->getMicroTimeStart());
    }, &$result);
```

If it makes sense, you can also persist this into the database (by modifying orm fiels and then persisting).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I have taught about that option too, but I need the DQL approach, because I use the knp sort component, and that only accepts an query (besides that, I also want to have as less code as possible :) )

Comment: You may have to write a custom hydrator for this.  Or add the duration field as part of the database table.

Comment: So there is no real possibility to somehow merge / set a custom value directly via DQL (to an existing entity)?